# Custom WCF service - includeExceptionDetailInFaults

Tags: wcf, exception-handling, cksdev

I've got a custom WCF service that I created using the CKS toolkit for SharePoint.

How do I enable `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` in these services?

The way I understand it is, when using `BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint` SharePoint creates the endpoints dynamically?

So where do i enabled exceptions?

Thx

### UPDATE

I can decorate the service implementation with `[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]` which works, but it's preferable to have this in config??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          **<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />**
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Yes, but which config file does that go in. web.config in ISAPI ?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is the place.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking as answer