# How do I enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults for REST (ListData.svc)

Tags: rest

I see this answer: [Custom WCF service - includeExceptionDetailInFaults](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37095/custom-wcf-service-includeexceptiondetailinfaults) but when I attempt to do that it complains that the "Name" attribute of the "behavior" element is null.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to transfer exceptions details, just to debug? Then just enable wcf tracing in web config and get exceptions in trace viewer.

Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) to know how to enable WCF tracing.

Comment: If I enable exception details in the result then I do not have to log in to the server.

Comment: Yes, but It looks like you need such behavior only for debug purposes. Why end user has to watch your exceptions? My personal set of tools for debugging services consist of: Fiddler, ULC loggin inside service, WCF logging enabled if needed. It is enough to debug and no problems with service config and multiple IIS bindings.

Comment: This is a development server and is not accessed outside of the development team.